# connecting a network camera to python/ opencv

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, ip-camera

I've trained my CNN model with python/OpenCV using Tensorflow and I used it to test images successfully.
I'm trying now to test my program with an external IP camera.
I think I can do that using the camera's IP address, but I don't know how to modify that in my code.
Any help would be useful
here is my program:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

img = image.load_img("computer vision/train/NOK/1.BMP")
plt.imshow(img)

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)


train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory("computer vision/train/", target_size = (200,200) , batch_size = 3,class_mode = 'binary')
validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory("computer vision/valid/", target_size = (200,200) , batch_size = 3,class_mode = 'binary')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (200,200,3)),tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation= 'relu'),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid')
                                   ])

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy']
             )

model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset,
                   steps_per_epoch=3,
                   epochs=10,
                   validation_data=validation_dataset)


dir_path = "C:/Users/Dell/OneDrive/Bureau/Nouveau dossier (2)"


for i in os.listdir(dir_path):

    img = image.load_img(dir_path + '//' + i, target_size=(200, 200))

    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    X = image.img_to_array(img)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
    images = np.vstack([X])
    val = model.predict(images)
    if val == 0:
        print("NOK")
    else:
        print("OK")
```

Comment: Please do not put your code snippets in quotes (edited); you probably meant to use inverse quotes, which are however unnecessary when you use indentation, as you do here.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You can check OpenCV's **VideoCapture(filename,apiPreference)** function.

According to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) this can be used to open a video file or image file sequence or a capturing device or a IP video stream for video capturing.

As for integrating this into your code, the general concept can be summarized as follows:
1)receive the input video signal (eg. using VideoCapture()),
2)modify it according to your model's input requirements (if for example your model is to classify grayscale images of 224x224 you should dispatch images from your video stream in a custom-defined frequency, convert them to grayscale and rescale them to fit into your model, convert them to tensors etc..)

In general, since you have already trained your model, you just have to develop/modify your **inference code** by using your pre-trained model, and process and format your incoming signal in the same form that you fed your training data at the first place..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want say that, you want to stream with your ip camera right?

Try this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCamera(1)
cap.open('https://yourip:port')
```

Maybe this would work!

and If you want to use your mobile as an Ip camera, there's an app called Ip Camera

Just install it and start your server

and you'll be able to access it by this url- `cap.open('https://yourip:port/video')`